# Place voice call, to have inapp feel (or just hide the default phone disconnected UI)

Tags: android, android-dialog

Currently when we place a voice phone call through the app the entire screen is taken up by the call UI. Is there a way to enclose the call feel into a dialog and provide it with some margin's so that the user need not remember to press back to get into the app, after the call is complete ?

Basically I dont want the customer to need to remember to press "back" button.

I am using the code below to place the call. But instead of opening the last activity, its opening the first launch screen. I need it to just hide.

Edit :

```
PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneCallListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + cabbiePhoneNumber));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

I am now using PhoneStateListener for listening to the phone state.

```
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;
    String LOG_TAG = "LOGGING 123";
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // phone ringing
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // active
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");
            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            // run when class initial and phone call ended,
            // need detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");
            if (isPhoneCalling) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");
                // restart app
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                        getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                isPhoneCalling = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. Basically just needed to not do the getBaseContext().find the parent and launch thingy.

I needed to launch the activity that I needed.

> BookingExperience.this.showDriverDetails();

```
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;
    String LOG_TAG = "LOGGING 123";

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // phone ringing
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // active
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");
            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            // run when class initial and phone call ended,
            // need detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");
            if (isPhoneCalling) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");
                // restart app
                BookingExperience.this.showDriverDetails();
                // getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                // getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                // i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                // startActivity(i);
                isPhoneCalling = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Voice call without built-in Call UI  is not possible from an SDK application**. You have to roll your own firmware to achieve this.

Comment: if it was not possible, I wouldn't have asked it. Fixed it.

Comment: That's nice:) My answer was for your first unedited question. ie, inapp voice call is not possible without call UI.

Comment: Oh yeah!! That you are correct. Please edit your answer for that. I cant accept your answer, but I will upvote it as you make it sound more "complete". Thanks again.

Comment: That was helpful for me too